# How to use MySQL JSON_SET to a document with numeric key?

Tags: mysql

I have a json field name `shipping_info` in mysql table with the following sample data

```
{
    "shipping": {
        "0": {
            "phone": "(222) 222-2222",
            "address1": "streeta",
            "address2": null,
            "address3": null,
            "attention": "company",
            "phone_ext": null,
            "postal_code": "91406",
            "proper_city": "VAN NUYS",
            "address_type": "u",
            "city_or_town": "VAN NUYS",
            "country_code": "US"
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to update the value in this path `shipping.0.address1`.
This is my query so far, but it doesn't seem to work

```
UPDATE cart_items 
SET shipping_info = JSON_SET(
    shipping_info, 
    '$.shipping[0].address1', 'new value'
) 
WHERE cart_item_id= 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working with the following query:

```
UPDATE cart_items 
SET shipping_info = JSON_SET(
   shipping_info, 
   '$.shipping."0".address1', 'new value'
) 
WHERE cart_item_id= 1;
```

I'm posting this as an answer just in case someone will also encounter this same scenario.

Comment: Tested now and it works, thank you. They key was to surround they JSON key with ".